# how to use Map in java which was used in python (dict() or {})

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, dictionary, hashmap

I want to rewrite this code from python to java:

```py
def updateJson(db, offer_update):
    kv = list(offer_update.items())
    for key, value in kv:
        old_value = db.get(key)
        if old_value is None:
            db[key] = value
        else:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                updateJson(db[key], value)
            else:
                if old_value == value:
                    del offer_update[key]
                else:
                    db[key] = value


def main():
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    services = []
    d = dict()
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, *words = input().split(' ')
        a, b = int(a), int(b)
        services.append((set(words[:a]), set(words[a:])))
    for _ in range(m):
        q = json.loads(input())
        trace_id = q['trace_id']
        id_ = q['offer']['id']
        updateJson(d, {id_: q['offer']})
        for t, sh in services:
///
```

My basic knowledge of python says that the updateJson method takes two dictionaries (in java it is a Map), BUT why is an object and a string passed there when recursively calling this method?

```py
updateJson(db[key], value)
```

I would like to do this, but Java doesn't seem to allow it.
Basic Example

```java
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", 1);
HashMap<String, Object> map1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) map.get("1");
System.out.println(map1);
```

Will error

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.util.HashMap (java.lang.Integer and java.util.HashMap are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Please tell me how to correctly rewrite code from python to java, if python does not have explicit types and it is not clear what the method accepts when called recursively

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `(HashMap<String, Object>) map.get("1");`